Angular upgrade 7 to 8
When I use this command ng update @angular/cli@8 @angular/core@8
I'm encountering an issue while trying to update Angular CLI and its core packages:
Package not installed: "@angular/core". Skipping.
Error: Command failed: npm get //registry.npmjs.org/:username
npm error The //registry.npmjs.org/:username option is protected, and can not be retrieved in this way

I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Cleaned npm cache with npm cache clean --force.
Updated npm to the latest version with npm install -g npm@latest.

Despite these steps, the issue persists. Any suggestions on how to resolve this error?
PS C:\Users\og10\Desktop\5.07\ETerkinAngular-master\Portal\ClientApp> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: portal@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@7.2.16
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^7.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^17.0.0" from @coreui/angular@2.17.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@coreui/angular
npm ERR!   @coreui/angular@"^2.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\og10\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\og10\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-07-05T14_02_24_236Z-debug.log

I want to upgrade my Angular 7 project to Angular 8.

Which command did you run that led to the error?

These are versions which are over 5 years old and well out of support. It would be advisable to try NodeJS v12 and npm v6, which were latest at the time.

ng update @angular/cli@8 @angular/core@8

According to the update guide, the correct command is NG_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1 npx @angular/cli@8 update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8

Package not installed: "@angular/core". Skipping.
packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed. Ignoring.
its not working

Sounds like you are trying to run very old commands on newer versions of the underlying software. As @JSONDerulo suggested, you should install older versions of node and npm.

When using Node.js version 12 I'm getting this error:
The installed Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable version.
Installing a temporary version to perform the update.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Node.js version v12.13.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.19.
